# How to rearrange this equation and find the constant?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Okay so I've been working a mechanics problem and it has boiled down to this.

I want to find $v(t)$ and I currently have that.

$$t+c_1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{gk}}\ln{\frac{\sqrt{g/k}-v}{\sqrt{g/k}+v}}$$ where $c_1$ is a constant of integration.

My thoughts are so, at $t=0$ the particle has some velocity $v$ so we will end up with $c_1=...$ but I'm not sure how to determine $c_1$ I think I need to sub in $t=0$ or something but I don't know how to do it.

Then obviously I need to rearrange to find $v(t)$ and then I am done, but this is easier said than done considering this equation is quite ugly to be honest. Any help with me on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate the log function to one side as follows:-
$$2\sqrt{gk}(t+c_1)=ln{\frac{\sqrt{g/k}-v}{\sqrt{g/k}+v}}$$ 
then take the exponential of both sides
$$\frac{\sqrt{g/k}-v}{\sqrt{g/k}+v}=e^{2\sqrt{gk}(t+c_1)}$$
leading to $v(t)$ being
$$v(t)=\frac{\sqrt{g/k}(1-e^{2\sqrt{gk}(t+c_1)})}{1+e^{2\sqrt{gk}(t+c_1)}}$$

Now, in order to find the value of $c_1$ at time $t=0$ and $v(0)=V$, you need to make $c_1$ the subject of the formula, leading to
$$c_1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{gk}}\left(ln{\frac{\sqrt{g/k}-v}{\sqrt{g/k}+v}}-2t\sqrt{gk}\right)$$
Set $t=0$ and $v(0)=V$, and you are done.

Comment: I literally just managed to get that working through it step by step carefully thanks! Is there anyway to determine what $c_1$ would be though assuming the particle has some velocity $V$ at $t=0$???

Comment: Just put t=0 and v=V into your first equation.

Comment: @CallumDavids See my further edits.

Comment: Awesome guys thanks!